# SELECT transaction seems to be cached on postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The server I am running distributes 'jobs' out to users, however, I'm having an issue where users get distributed the same job. I believe this is either a concurrency issue or a caching issue.

Here's the query I currently use (note the `{...}` is for python formatting):

```sql
UPDATE "job" 
SET pending=true, completor='{client.uuid}' 
WHERE "number" IN 
    (
     SELECT "number" FROM "job" 
     WHERE pending=false AND closed=false AND gpu=true 
     ORDER BY "number" ASC LIMIT 1
    );
```

Afterwards, I fetch the job where `completor='{client.uuid}'` and it fetches the job that was updated. I thought that using this system would make the entire process run in a single transaction, avoiding any concurrency issues.

However, after testing I found that clients can be given the same job even after 5 seconds apart from each other. Could this be a caching issue, or do I need to implement a locking mechanism?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which [transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/transaction-iso.html) are your using ?

Comment: I'm not too sure. Perhaps the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must be in concurrency of transactions updating the same table.
To force the row not to be updated twice, the transaction that first looks at it must lock it, and other transactions must skip it.

i guess this is your solution

```sql
UPDATE "job" 
SET pending=true, completor='{client.uuid}' 
WHERE "number" IN 
    (
     SELECT "number" FROM "job" 
     WHERE pending=false AND closed=false AND gpu=true 
     ORDER BY "number" ASC LIMIT 1
     FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED -- locking
    )
  AND pending=false AND closed=false AND gpu=true -- and doublecheck
;
```

even if two transactions start at same time, only one of them will lock the row and update it, and another transaction will lock the next row.